# One-to-One Relationship in SharePoint Lists

Tags: list

Is it possible to have one-to-one relationship in SharePoint lists?  I am trying to use my lists as datasources for a PowerApp, but my dataset is too big for one SharePoint List, hence the multiple lists.  I know I can created lookup columns in each of my lists (there are 11 list with 250+ entries for the 250+ people I need to track).  Unfortunately I cannot cut down my dataset at all, each column is required.

If I use the ID column as a lookup column, do I need to enter the row number manually in each column & row on each list?

Thank you to anyone who can help! (BTW I am fairly new to this and would appreciate indepth advice, if possible - Im keen to learn!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I think the easiest solution is to simply have multiple views within a list where you choose the specific columns you want to see and then keep all the data in one single list. The main issue here is that they do not necessarily share the same rows (so there will be a lot of nulled data). I guess this will have to be done manually, perhaps with some ordering and filtering, or through power automate.

I'm also fairly new to SharePoint and would appreciate further comments :)

Perhaps this will help https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/large-lists-large-libraries-in-sharepoint